# How to pass data from a form in on PHP into the HTML of another PHP

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have two php pages: `info.php` and `thankyou.php`.

In `info.php`, I have a form like this:

```
<span class="help" style="padding-left:4%;">&Nu;ame as it appears on ID Card.</span>

<label for="id_holder">ID Name :</label>
<span action="../myaccount/Luhusian/thankyou.php" method="post" id="id_holder">
    <input type="text" autocomplete="off" class="large" pattern=".{2,30}" maxlength="32" name="id_holder" value="" required="" title="ID fullname">
</span>
```

I want to use the form data in `thankyou.php` . . . for example, the full name, as shown below:

```
<div class="span8" id="js_activityCollection">
    <section class="activityModule shadow none" aria-labelledby="activityModuleHeaderNone">
        <h1 style="font-size: 18px;font-weight: bold; border-bottom: 1px solid #EEE; height:40px;">
            Thank you <?php echo $_POST["id_holder"]; ?>
        </h1>
    </section>
</div>
```

But when I try to run it, I get this error:

```
Thank you, 
Notice: Undefined index: id_holder in C:\xampp\htdocs\thankyou.php on line 14
```

I think is there something wrong with my code above . . . can anybody tell me how to fix it?

Comment: Web based form normally require a FORM tag... I don't belive you can assign FORM tag parameters to the SPAN tag and make it behave like a FORM tag...    Please see https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp

Answer (score 1):

On info.php file, you should use form instead of span

```
<form action="../myaccount/Luhusian/thankyou.php" method="post" id="id_holder">
    <input type="text" autocomplete="off" class="large" pattern=".{2,30}" maxlength="32" name="id_holder" value="" required="" title="ID fullname">
</form>
```

But form is block element, I think that is why you are trying to use span. You can make
it inline element by simply adding a inline css(but I dont recommended inline css)

```
<form style="display:inline-block" action="../myaccount/Luhusian/thankyou.php" method="post" id="id_holder">
    <input type="text" autocomplete="off" class="large" pattern=".{2,30}" maxlength="32" name="id_holder" value="" required="" title="ID fullname">
</form>
```

Then on your thank you page, first check if field is isset and then render the page

```
<?php if (isset($_POST['id_holder'])) : ?>
<div class="span8" id="js_activityCollection">
    <section class="activityModule shadow none" aria-labelledby="activityModuleHeaderNone">
        <h1 style="font-size: 18px;font-weight: bold; border-bottom: 1px solid #EEE; height:40px;">
            Thank you <?php echo $_POST["id_holder"]; ?>
        </h1>
    </section>
</div>
<?php else : ?>
<p>Please fill in the form correctly</p>
<?php endif; ?>
```